# Google play developer console tablet optimization tips-how to fix?

Tags: android

I published my app in play market and I received a message:Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet screen densities,category:Use Assets Designed for Tablet Screens.

1-I have a size of (hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi) launcher icons in a directory
mipmap

2-manifest code:
`<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />`

3-minSdkVersion 21,targetSdkVersion 23

4-my permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I do not understand what the problem is. Any replies will be happy!. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Add good screenshots for tablets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but whether due screenshots appear this message? Or have you had this problem? and replacing screenshot helped.

Comment: Read about it mostly. Just ignored this issue after some time.

Comment: but then my application will not be available on tablets and it worries me.